# How to write good if/else-if structures in PHP

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

Somebody with good skills in PHP can help me to correct this code? I have a problem it is stuck at `else if(level >= 10)` if the `level` is larger that 10.

```
var level = m.level;

if(level < 10)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco">' + level + '</span>';
} 

else if(level >= 10)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco10">' + level + '</span>';
}        

else if(level >= 30)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco30">' + level + '</span>';
}            

else if(level >= 50)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco50">' + level + '</span>';
} 

else if(level >= 80)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco80">' + level + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @saw303 Problem is clear. Let's say the value of `level` is 50, it will do only level 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

```
var level = m.level;
var levelclass = 'levelco';

if(level >= 10) levelclass = 'levelco10';
if(level >= 30) levelclass = 'levelco30';
if(level >= 50) levelclass = 'levelco50';
if(level >= 80) levelclass = 'levelco80';

level = '<span class="' + levelclass + '">' + level + '</span>';
```

Reversing it and using `else if` makes it more efficient since it stops executing once a condition is fulfilled:

```
if(level >= 80) levelclass = 'levelco80';
else if(level >= 50) levelclass = 'levelco50';
else if(level >= 30) levelclass = 'levelco30';
else if(level >= 10) levelclass = 'levelco10';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also give the upper level and also use `elseif`, if PHP, coz this looks like JavaScript:

```
var level = m.level;

if (level < 10) {
    level = '<span class="levelco">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 10 && level < 30) {
    level = '<span class="levelco10">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 30 && level < 50) {
    level = '<span class="levelco30">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 50 && level < 80) {
    level = '<span class="levelco50">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 80) {
    level = '<span class="levelco80">' + level + '</span>';
}
```

If that's not possible, reverse the conditions:

```
var level = m.level;

if (level < 10) {
    level = '<span class="levelco">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 80) {
    level = '<span class="levelco80">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 50) {
    level = '<span class="levelco50">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 30) {
    level = '<span class="levelco30">' + level + '</span>';
} else if (level >= 10) {
    level = '<span class="levelco10">' + level + '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve this problem, but it's basically down to the second if will capture all of the following conditions (level >= 10 will match all of the following conditions).

Solution 1 is just re-order the conditions.

```
level = m.level;


if(level < 10)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco">' + level + '</span>';
} 
else if(level >= 80)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco80">' + level + '</span>';
}
else if(level >= 50)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco50">' + level + '</span>';
} 
else if(level >= 30)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco30">' + level + '</span>';
}    
else if(level >= 10)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco10">' + level + '</span>';
}
```

Option 2 is to put a limit on each if...

```
level = m.level;


if(level < 10)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco">' + level + '</span>';
} 

else if(level >= 10 && level <30)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco10">' + level + '</span>';
}        

else if(level >= 30 && level < 50)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco30">' + level + '</span>';
}            

else if(level >= 50 && level < 80)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco50">' + level + '</span>';
} 

else if(level >= 80)
{
    level = '<span class="levelco80">' + level + '</span>';
}
```